# Checkbox getting duplicated after the third foreach

Tags: laravel

[image]

How to remove duplicate checkbox from the blade?

[image]

```
<div class="card">
             <div class="card-content">
       @php
         $models = ['users','profile','Products','Clients','Orders'];
         $maps = ['create','read','update','delete'];
        @endphp
                  <div class="row">
                   <div class="col s12">
                       <table class="mt-1">
                          <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>Module Permission</th>
                              <th>Create</th>
                              <th>Read</th>
                              <th>Update</th>
                              <th>Delete</th>
                            </tr>
                          </thead>
                          <tbody>
                           <tr>
                          @foreach ($models as $model)
                            <td>{{ $model }} </td>
                            @foreach ($maps as $map)
                            <td>
                             <label> 
                                     <input type="hidden" name='permissions[]' id='test' value="">
                                    <input name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $map . '-' . $model }}"
                                      @foreach($role->permissions as $r)
                                     @if  ($r->name == ($map . '-' . $model))
                                      {{ 'checked' }} @endif
                                      <span></span>
                                @endforeach
                            </label>
                            </td>
                             @endforeach 
                              </tr>
                             @endforeach
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                        <!-- </div> -->
                    </div>
                   </div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you .. now its working after pushing the Span after the foreach loop...

```
<input name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $map . '-' . $model }}"
@foreach($role->permissions as $r)
    {{ ($r->name == ($map . '-' . $model)) ? 'checked >' : '>' }}
@endforeach
<span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

your checkbox have no end, and I replace if instruction to ternary instruction :

```
<input name="permissions[]" type="checkbox" value="{{ $map . '-' . $model }}"
    @foreach($role->permissions as $r)
        {{ ($r->name == ($map . '-' . $model)) ? 'checked >' : '>' }}
        <span></span>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: not working, that was my first try, somehow its working but out of the boarder. check the second pic.